# ESP8266 interrupts issue

Tags: interrupt, sensors, arduino-esp8266, arduino-esp32

i am using esp8266 to calculate the rpm using hall 3144 sensor, and while doing so there is an issue arises in code.

```
void exti_callback()
{
Serial.println("working");
}
void setup() {

pinMode(D1,INPUT);
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(D1),exti_callback,FALLING);
Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
Serial.println("Not working");
}
```

upon further investigation i understand that this specific line

```
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(D1),exti_callback,FALLING);
```

of code is giving me error. Earlier i was using D2 pin and was still facing the same error so i thought i am using wrong pin to get the interrupt so i change that pin to pin D1 but same error still persists.
How did i know that this line is giving me error because if i comment out this line, whole code works perfectly, and void loop () also starts to work fine then.

I have even tried using different baud rate, different upload rate but the issue persists.
I have even change the USB cable, USB port and what not but still error came.
This is the error.

```
load 0x4010f000, len 3424, room 16
tail 0
chksum 0x2e
load 0x3fff20b8, len 40, room 8 
tail 0
chksum 0x2b
csum 0x2b
v00041f10
~ld
⸮⸮⸮⸮o쒜p⸮⸮n|⸮l⸮⸮$`b⸮⸮|r⸮$⸮o⸮⸮o⸮
ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)
```

this same error is keep getting generated again and again.

[image]

I have even tried using different baud rate, different upload rate but the issue persists.
I have even change the USB cable, USB port and what not but still error came.

---

EDIT#1

I tried your Button code as said by **@MartinR** its giving same error. But i have made a progress

```
int flag = 0;
void ICACHE_RAM_ATTR hallInterrupt();
void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
pinMode(D5, INPUT_PULLUP);
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(D5), hallInterrupt, FALLING);
}

void loop() {
Serial.println(flag);
delay(500);

}
void hallInterrupt()
{
flag = 1;
delay(500);
}
```

this code at least run without giving the previous error but still this code unable to enter the interrupt function. I mean to say that this code is printing 0, but as soon i provide some interrupts to hall sensor using magnets it's giving me new kind of hex numberical error.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question and not just state that you have an issue. We _all_ have issues. Also take the [tour].

Comment: 1) For ESP8266, ISR() function need to have `ICACHE_RAM_ATTR` attribute (meaning to run it from RAM). Read [documentation](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#interrupts) on interrupt. 2) add `volatile` to the declaration of `flag` to avoid it from being over-optimized away by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining D1 as GPIO 5 which is the corresponding pin if im not wrong.

```
#define D1 5
```

If somehow D1 is reserved try calling it different (BUTTON for example).

```
#define BUTTON 5

void exti_callback()
{
Serial.println("working");
}
void setup() {

pinMode(BUTTON,INPUT);
attachInterrupt(BUTTON,exti_callback,FALLING);
Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
Serial.println("Not working");
delay(500);
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

#EDIT:

[Code Working Screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoTsT.png)

[Your edited code working Screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5F0a.png)

Comment: it's not working still. I have used all the pin from D1 to D8 still the error is same. Could u help me to resolve the error, like what that error is trying to say?

Comment: Have you tried a code like this?

       I eddited the previous comment with the actual modified code.
The error code is due to a boot of the board due to a possible coding error.

Comment: And btw, watch out the function attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(D1),exti_callback,FALLING);
The function should look like this: attachInterrupt(GPIOPin, ISR, Mode);
so for the first argument just put the GPIO pin.

Comment: Kindly look into the question again. i have edited it with my progress.

Comment: Well, I don´t know what to say... I just tried the code in my ESP board and works perfectly for me. I would try to change the hall sensor for a simple button for testing, but the code i provided you just works fine. (Also added a delay for debuging...)

Comment: I just edited the main answer to add a picture that shows the code i provided you working. Also the code you provided (by adding a "#define D5 14" in the first line) works for me too, i also added a picture showing this in the main answer.